# Order by date but add important at first in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table what looks like that:

```
ID | title | author | timestamp | livetime | special
```

My goal is select all from table where livetime is larger than current timestamp and order it by timestamp desc BUT records where "special" is true must be in first (of course, also ordered). It's possible to do only with the MySQL?

My SQL Query looks that:

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE livetime > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can sort by two columns. Value of true is 1 and false 0, so you need to sort in the descending order.

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE livetime > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ORDER BY special DESC, timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM ads 
WHERE livetime > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
ORDER BY special <> 1,
         timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE livetime > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ORDER BY special, timestamp DESC
```